# Access multi dimension NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays using UITableView indexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a `UITableView` with a dynamic amount of sections and rows, I am wanting to use a custom `cell.accessoryView` which I have managed to create using the following code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [stackRotationController pop];
    cell = (TreeCell *)[cuttingTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findbitting@2x.png"]];
    NSNumber *newState;

    if ([[selectedStatesMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == NO) {
        newState = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
    } else {
        newState = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        cell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [selectedStatesMArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newState];

    //....
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *currentNumber = [uniqueKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *currentArray = [sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView objectForKey:currentNumber];
    cellDictionary = [currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TreeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
//    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findbitting@2x.png"]];

    if ([[selectedStatesMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == NO) {
        cell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
    }


    cell.itemsDictionary = cellDictionary;
    cellDictionary = nil;
    [cell drawCell];

    return cell;
}
```

The issue being with this is that it added a tick to every section that have a row tick... which is not what I wanted  so I changed the code above to work off an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays`.

However now I get an error

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [stackRotationController pop];
    cell = (TreeCell *)[cuttingTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findbitting@2x.png"]];
    NSNumber *newState;



    NSMutableArray *tempInternalMArray = [selectedStatesMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    if ([[tempInternalMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == NO) {
        newState = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
    } else {
        newState = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
        cell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [tempInternalMArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newState];
    [selectedStatesMArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:tempInternalMArray];

    //....
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *currentNumber = [uniqueKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *currentArray = [sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView objectForKey:currentNumber];
    cellDictionary = [currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TreeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UIImageView *checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findbitting@2x.png"]];

    NSMutableArray *tempInternalMArray = [[selectedStatesMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] mutableCopy];

    if ([[tempInternalMArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == NO) { // error happens here
        cell.accessoryView = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryView = checkmark;
    }


    cell.itemsDictionary = cellDictionary;
    cellDictionary = nil;
    [cell drawCell];

    return cell;
}
```

When I go to display the very first cell the app falls over with the following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

I get the values into `selectedStatesMArray` from my parser delegate like so. This code is called before the `cellForRow` code is called so it should be working but is not.

```
NSNumber *newState;
newState = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

NSMutableArray *tempSelectedStatesMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < [sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView count]; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *tempSectionSelectedStatsMArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j = 0; j < [[sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]] count]; j++) {
        [tempSectionSelectedStatsMArray addObject:newState];
    }
    [tempSelectedStatesMArray addObject:tempSectionSelectedStatsMArray];

}
selectedStatesMArray = [tempSelectedStatesMArray mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an empty array but rather than try and unscramble your code, I would suggest you use an array of [`NSMutableIndexSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s.  It will make life much easier for you.

Let's start with the initialisation method.  You should call this as soon as you have finished loading data but before any call to `reloadData` on the tableview.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *selectStates;

-(void) initialiseSelectStates {
   self.selectedStates=[NSMutableArray new];
   for (int i=0;i<uniqueKeys.count;i++) {
       [self.selectedStates addObject:[NSMutableIndexSet new]];
   }
}
```

Now, your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [stackRotationController pop];
    cell = (TreeCell *)[cuttingTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSMutableIndexSet *sectionSelects=[self.selectedStats objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    if ([sectionSelects containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
       [selectionSelects removeIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.accessoryView=nil;
    }
    else {
       [selectionSelects addIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.accessoryView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findbitting@2x.png"]];
    }
    //....
}
```

And your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *currentNumber = [uniqueKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *currentArray = [sortedDictionaryArraysForTableView objectForKey:currentNumber];
    NSMutableIndexSet *sectionSelects=[self.selectedStats objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TreeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    // cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if ([sectionSelects containsIndex:indexPath.row]) { 
       cell.accessoryView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"findbitting@2x.png"]];
    }
    else {
       cell.accessoryView=nil;
    }

    cell.itemsDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[currentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell drawCell];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Okay sorry for the late reply I have been reading up all about  NSMutableIndexSets wrote a small test program and it worked then applied what you showed me to my app and it worked perfectly!!! not only that but I learnt something new today! So thats cool! thanks for your help.