# remove objects of selected row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

hey i have created a table view with multiple selection and checkmark accessory which users can tap on and select relevant rows in table... retailerid and retailernaem  of individual selection will be stored in NSMutableDictionary and all dictionaries in return will be stored in NSMutableArray... i have done this till now

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    NSMutableDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [theDictionary setObject:[[BrandsArray valueForKey:@"RetailerID"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"id"];

    [theDictionary setObject:[[BrandsArray valueForKey:@"RetailerName"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"name"];

    [selectedIndexes addObject:theDictionary];

}
else {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    NSLog(@"this is deselected row %@",[selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [selectedIndexes removeObject:dictionary];

    dictionary = nil;
}

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}
```

now problem is in the else block... its not removing objects from randomly selected row...
for example if i select first row and then deselect the same it works fine but when i select the last row and then deselect the same app crash..

Comment: Did you try [tableview reloadData] after removing the object ?

Comment: Your method is flawed - Your `selectedIndexes` array will not contain the same number or order of elements as your data model.  You should use an `NSMutableIndexSet`. See my answer here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050337/access-multi-dimension-nsmutablearray-of-nsmutablearrays-using-uitableview-index/25050937?noredirect=1#comment39005563_25050937

Comment: app crashes when i deselct row so cant call [tableview reloadData]. @kkocabiyik

Comment: @Paulw11 i am looking at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050337/access-multi-dimension-nsmutablearray-of-nsmutablearrays-using-uitableview-index/25050937?noredirect=1#comment39005563_25050937) dealt with multiple sections, I will provide a simpler, single section answer here

First, declare a property for your selection state -

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableIndexSet *selectStates;
```

Initialise it in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.selectStates=[NSMutableIndexSet new];
```

The use it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.selectStates containsIndex:[indexPath.row]) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone]; 
        [self.selectStates removeIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [self.selectStates addIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

You will also need to check the `selectedStates` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to set the correct accessory when the cell is scrolled back into view.  Just add the snippet -

```
if ([self.selectStates containsIndex:[indexPath.row]) {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone]; 
} else {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

If you need the ability to easily insert and delete rows then you can use an `NSMutableSet` instead of an `NSIndexSet` - just store the data source object.  If you do allow deletion you need to make sure that the object is removed from the set, if necessary, when the row is deleted.

First, declare a property for your selection state -

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableSet *selectStates;
```

Initialise it in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.selectStates=[NSMutableSet new];
```

The use it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    Brand *brand=(Brand *)[BrandsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // Change "Brand" to the appropriate object class

    if ([self.selectStates containsObject:brand) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone]; 
        [self.selectStates removeObject:brand];
    } else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [self.selectStates addObject:brand];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

You will also need to check the `selectedStates` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to set the correct accessory when the cell is scrolled back into view.  Just add the snippet -

```
if ([self.selectStates containsObject:brand) {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone]; 
} else {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply but server from which i am fetching table data is down.. i will test your method when server is running again...

Comment: can you explain me a little about NSMutableIndexSet... what value is stored in it.
and what is happening on this line : self.selectStates=[NSMutableIndexSet new];

Comment: An index set just contains a set of indexes - effectively integers. You can quickly test if the set contains or doesn't contain a given index. The line is just the newer, quicker way of saying `[[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init]`

Comment: In this case it would work, but in general, I am not sure if in good idea to use NSMutableIndexSet as data source for table views. Think what happens when the user wants to delete the 1-st row in a shopping list app for example.

Comment: That is a good point, I was just thinking about.  You can just use an NSSet - it is more expensive in terms of searching and memory, but not so much that it would have an impact.  I will update my answer to show how

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the way you use the array.

Let's say you select the last element from a table view with 10 cells. Then the array size is 1, but when you select again the last row, [selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; is trying to access the element with index 9 in the array, which does not exist at the moment.

Try to implement something like this:

```
NSInteger ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE = 100;

NSMutableArray *selectedIndexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE; ++i) {
    selectedIndexes[i] = [NSNull null];
}
```

Make selectedIndexes to be a property in your View Controller class, and whenever you use it, put self.selectedIndexes instead.

In the didSelectRow: atIndexPath: method, the first line is recommended to be:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

Then, write the code:

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    NSMutableDictionary *theDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [theDictionary setObject:[[BrandsArray valueForKey:@"RetailerID"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"id"];

    [theDictionary setObject:[[BrandsArray valueForKey:@"RetailerName"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"name"];

    [selectedIndexes replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:theDictionary];

} else {

    selectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    [selectedIndexes replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNull null]];

}
```

I hope it helps you. Let me know.

Comment: yes @Pavlusha i know the problem but dont know the solution ...!!

Comment: Or use an NSMutableIndexSet and reduce the whole mess to about 4 lines.  As well as the problem with the array there is also the issue of using the current `accessoryType` of the cell - This will be invalid once the cell is re-used

Comment: I just tried to explain what was the reason for the app crashing, and how can he correct it using the method he wants to use.

Comment: But your method will crash when there are 101 rows in the table - or if you increase the array to 1000 then it will crash at 1001 plus waste memory.

Comment: sorry for late reply but i think the server from which i am fetching table data is down.. i will test your method when server is running again...

Comment: yeaa  @Paulw11 is right i dont want ot limit no. of rows because i am fetching it from server and it can be 1000  or 2000.. i dont know

Comment: @Pavlusha - It still won't work because NSMutableArrays can't be sparse - You need to check if the element you are setting is beyond `ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE` and then expand the array capacity by inserting the appropriate number of nil objects and then track the new capacity!  Or, just use an NSMutableIndexSet and everything is done for you

Comment: I just put a constant for the purpose of quickly showing an example. In real-world, it is obvious we initialize the array with the size of the array containing the dictionary objects we want to use data for display.

Comment: What if you don't know the size. You may be paging results from a database or the user may be able add and delete rows.